# Regex to determine windows UPN

Tags: c#, regex

Using regex with the following example string format I would like to achieve the following:

user@domain.local

I would like to create a regex expression to retrieve specific parts of the string using named groups. I have the following working for domains but not for usernames:

```
(?<domain>([a-z0-9]+\.)*[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+).*(?<username>.*|)
```

https://regex101.com/r/nxL7my/3

My group for domain is populated but I don't understand why my group for username won't populate. Is it because the regex needs to return to the start of the string to find the last index of '@' and then select everything before it? (This is because a windows UPN logon could have an '@' symbol therefor this is a valid character).

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this: [`^(?<username>[^@]+)@(?<domain>(?:[a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/nxL7my/5)?

Comment: @ctwheels thats working perfectly! Do you think it would be difficult for the regex to cater for the 2 situations below:

domain\user
user@domain.local

Using the same named groups?

Comment: @ctwheels It doesn't appear to work with the following data:

us@er@domain.local

Any ideas? I thought about adding a $ into the first named group but had no luck

Comment: `us@er@domain.local` doesn't seem correct to me (only one `@` can be used), but you can use `^(?<username>.+)@(?<domain>(?:[a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]+)` in that case.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: c# is the language ill be using

Comment: that is absolutely perfect! my previous attempt to solve that was the below:
((?<domain>([a-z0-9]+\.)*[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+|^.*(?=(\\))).*(?<username>.*)|(\k<username>\A[a-z]))

much messier compared to your solution.

thanks very much @ctwheels :)

Comment: I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that this regex includes both `UPN` and `User logon name (pre-Windows 2000)` according to the OP's requirements (seen in the comments below the question) - thanks to [@Am_I_Helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3482140/am-i-helpful) for pointing this out. Thus, the regex below matches formats `user@domain.local` or `domain\user`.

[See regex in use here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3cusername%3e%5b%5e%40%5d%2b%29%40%28%3f%3cdomain%3e.%2b%29%7c%28%3f%3cdomain%3e%5b%5e%5c%5c%5d%2b%29%5c%5c%28%3f%3cusername%3e.%2b%29%29%24&i=user%40domain.local%0d%0adomain%5cuser&o=m)

```
^(?:(?<username>[^@]+)@(?<domain>.+)|(?<domain>[^\\]+)\\(?<username>.+))$
```

Simplifying the subpatterns, the first option is to match `^[^@]+@.+$`, and the second `^[^\\]+\\.+$`.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful thanks, you are helpful ;) I added a note for future readers stating what you have.

Comment: SORRY, my bad; ***domain\username*** is called `User logon name (pre-Windows 2000)`. I've made the necessary edit, and an upvote.